# Send UI to bakcground and get back UI of an application in linux

Tags: linux, ssh, background, putty, nohup

I'm running linux VM, OS is rhel 6.5, I'll get access the machine via Putty(SSH) only and I'll use export display option to run gui app's.

I've java application and have jar's, to run that application I'll use the below command in putty.

```
java -Dcms.console.available=false -Dcms.user="username" -Dcms.password="password" -jar LAUNCHER.jar
```

When I launch the application in command prompt, I'll get UI(If I want run this app as background process I'm using '&' at the end of the command, in this case also I'll get UI), after getting UI I'll select some options in UI then UI will load full components.

***Requirement:***

I want to send UI in background and I should get UI back(foreground the UI) when ever I want,
Is there any way to achieve this?

I've tried nohup & screen but it didn't worked, and googled no hlep found. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

`fg` and `bg` do just this:

> The POSIX standard specifies two commands for resuming suspended jobs
>   in the background and foreground, respectively bg and fg. These were
>   modeled after the Korn shell job control commands

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_(Unix)#Commands